# Trying to upload file via camera in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am trying to create a basic webview app for a H&S website we use that does not currently have an app. As part of this, I am wanting to add the ability to take a photo and upload directly using the camera. I have gotten it working to the point of it will open the camera and take the photo, but it will not upload it. Any help?

```
    public class MainActivity<uri> extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView web;

    String webUrl = "https://app.safetymonitor.nz/Dashboard";

    public Context context;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.loadUrl(webUrl);
        WebSettings mywebsettings = web.getSettings();
        mywebsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        CustomWebViewClient client = new CustomWebViewClient(this);
        web = findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setWebViewClient(client);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mywebsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebsettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        mywebsettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebsettings.setSavePassword(true);
        mywebsettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        mywebsettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                return true;
            }

            private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

                File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                imageStorageDir = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                return imageStorageDir;
            }

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                try {
                    File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);   

                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser((ValueCallback<uri>) uploadMsg, "");
            }
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // code for all versions except of Lollipop
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }

                Uri result = null;

                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue((uri) result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }

        } // end of code for all versions except of Lollipop

        // start of code for Lollipop only
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            // check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                    // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;

        } // end of code for Lollipop only


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (web.canGoBack()) {

            web.goBack();
        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
 } 
   class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    private Activity activity;
    public CustomWebViewClient(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView web, String url){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView web, WebResourceRequest request){
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This source was very helpful in this problem.

https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView

And after hours, I customized tht repository for myself, just for adding a file from camera. I hope this code helps you:

https://gist.github.com/danialnoaein/61448bcfac9615b4fdccce5569679d6f

Comment: This is incredible thank you! Works perfectly :) you are a life saver.

Comment: I only just started this account and it says I need 15 rep to up vote. But I promise I will come back and upvote as soon as I can!